# PHP treating local array as global

Tags: php, variables, global, local

I have a foreach like so:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $postArray[] = array(
    "title" => $post->title,
    "date" => date("d.m.Y", $post->created),
    // ... etc
  );

  var_dump($postArray);
}
```

`$postArray` is not delcared anywhere outside of this loop, and yet each loop iteration is ADDING to the existing array as if this variable is global, rather than creating a new one!

Is this a PHP setting? Bearing in mind I haven't really changed any settings from whatever default WAMP gives me. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the scope of this foreach? Note that unlike C/C++ and some other languages, in PHP {} doesn't create new scope.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a global variable but the way your syntax is written, it becomes global after the first iteration. This is because you are using the `array_push` shorthand of `[]`. Usually we use this as a synonym to `array_push()`

What you want to do is this -

```
$postArray = array(
  ...
);
```

That way, on each iteration, you will get a brand new `$postArray` object.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has function-level scope, not a block-level one. The variable indeed is a global, if this code is not in a function/class method, or it is local for the function, not for the loop

Answer (score 1):

`$myArray[] = $newVariable;` will append to the array.

If you want a fresh array, just redeclare, or empty the array at the beginning of each loop.

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[] = $data;
```

Answer (score -2):

foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

here we are using foreach which itself supports array .

Comment: take a look at the question again. I think you have mis-read it or something. Your answer doesn't really have anything to do with the question...

Comment: It's great that you are trying and you should continue to do so! :) However, in this case I think you should look at the question again. You are not answering the question. There is no problem with the `foreach` loop, there are no errors being raised. The only problem was that the array was being appened to instead of being initialized every iteration of the loop.